# Simple Rails ActiveRecord stars count query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is my simple question. How do I retrieve 'rateable_id's sum of stars count for 'dimension': foundation in descending order?
What chain of queries to use?

In table rates:

```
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 11
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: foundation
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:23.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:23.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 12
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: originality
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:24.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:24.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 13
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: dynamics
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:25.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:25.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 14
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: execution
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:26.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:26.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 15
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: battle
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:27.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:27.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 16
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: foundation
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:30.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:30.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 17
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: originality
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 18
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: dynamics
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 19
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: battle
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:32.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:32.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 25
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: foundation
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:46.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:46.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 26
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: originality
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:49.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:49.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 27
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: dynamics
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:51.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:51.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 28
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: execution
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:53.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:53.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 29
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: battle
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:54.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:54.000000000 Z
```

Thank you!I  Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is the n-th time I've seen this. The way you ask it, try this:

```
Rate.where(dimension: "foundation").sum(:stars, group: :rateable_id, order: "sum_stars desc").map{|a,b| {"rateable_id"=>a, "sum_stars"=>b}}
```